# To add a new line into the JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

To add a new line into a JavaScript string can I use the following code?

Is it according to programming standards? Is there another way to do this?

For example,

```
var string = "check";
alert(string);
var newstring = string + "\n\n";
alert(newstring);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is fine. If you are using alert for the debugging purposes, Please use
`console.log("string + "\n");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
\n
```

is the right way to handle new lines in alert boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `\n` everytime you want a new line in your string :

```js
var str = 'Test\nTest2\nTest3';
alert(str);
```